# Call Django view from a template

Tags: python, django, templates, view

I want to call a Django view from a Django template. Is there a tag to do that ?

For example, I want to create a view which manage my login form. So basically, this view will be used just to send the Django form to the html template.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your form may use the "action" parameter to direct to another html page for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this only for logging users, you should read [authenticating users in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth) which shows you how to write forms for logging in users.

If you want to send data filled in a form to a django view, simply set the `action` attribute of the form to the URL that is mapped to the view:

```
<form method="POST" action="/user-login">
  {% csrf_token %}
```

If you are using `POST`, you need to include `{% csrf_token %}` in your HTML form; and you should read the [documention on csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).

---

If you want to call some functionality from the template directly, write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), which allows you to execute arbitrary code and put the results in any template (or add them to the template context).

Comment: I want to use that for many reasons, not just for logging in users. So, no way to call a Django view from a Django template ?

Comment: afaik you cannot directly call a view, instead you can redirect to another url which will inturn call a view as i said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Map an url to that view. Redirect to that url from template.